# Jquery “Smooth Scroll” not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem:
I tried to make a smooth, slow scroll to the top when clicking on a link using jQuery. I used the following script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var ziel = $(this).attr("href");

  $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(ziel).offset().top
  }, 2000 , function (){location.hash = ziel;});
         });
});
```

On top of the page I have a `<h1>`-Tag with the id:start, and at the bottom I have a link defined: `a href="#start">Back to top</a>`

jQuery script included.

Does anybody know why it's not working in my case, but working  [here](http://www.drweb.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/animiertesscrollen.html)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, when creating code snippets, be sure to include all code (html & javascript)..

please take a look at the jsfiddle i put together for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/gfe3c43u/

HINT: Make sure that you are including the proper libraries wherever you are trying to run this code (note: my jsfiddle is using jquery 2.1.0)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It get 's more bizarre now.. Now klicking on my link doesn't change anything any more. When I e.g. do not include jquery any more, than it jumps to the right point (not smooth or anything) but when including the script, then it doesn't scroll any more... The only reason why it could be (what I wrote first was just a test, where it not worked) is that I use the silex framework.. so the link doesn't look like `href="#start">Back to top</a>`, it looks like `<a href="./allblogs#start">Back to top</a> ... Is this maybe the problem? Can I write something else as `href*=#` to have a specified link?

Comment: finally working, I had to write #start in the link, not the complete link, interesting thing, because without jquery, i had to write the complete link to jump there. Thanks anyway for help.